# Acess log to Jboss AS7 Server

Tags: server, jboss, jboss7.x

Where I work, I'm using Jboss AS7 Server to run about 4 applications.
We just finished developing a new application for our companie's partners.

The thing is we are currently getting a couple of connections from other countries like Nigeria and France (we are located in Brazil) and are suspecting that this new application might be opening a window to possible attacks.

Also it might be possible that the recent update to AS7 might be the issue.

What I want to know is if there is an extension for the AS7 Server which allows us to see which pages were accessed in which applications that are running on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The subsystem web should be able to produce an access log. In the standalone.xml, in the subsystem container :

```
           <virtual-server name="FQDN" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="FQDN"/>
            <access-log pattern="%t %a %u %r %s %b %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %S %T %{X-Transaction-ID}i"/>
        </virtual-server>
```

Those are standard ELF field, so you should be able to customize. Hope it helps.